# Not able to convert to text using formula if there is an error in cell value

Tags: excel, vba

The value of my cell is =@hdhd637373 which shows an error: #NAME? Upon entering. When I manually add a single quotation mark in front of the text the error goes away. How to achive this using formula or VBA. I have tried concat("'",A12) assuming value is entered in cell A12 but it returns error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FORMULATEXT()` function.

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA: The *value* of the cell is of type Error and can be checked using the function `IsError`. You get the formula text by using the property `Formula`.

The following code will locate all cells containing an invalid formula and replace it by putting the single quote-character in front of the text.

```
Sub correctErrors()
    Dim errorCells As Range
    On Error Resume Next        ' Prevent runtime error if no cells with error exists
    Set errorCells = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If errorCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In errorCells
        cell.Value = "'" & cell.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```